# How can the 'Open File...' dialog window be made larger, by default?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, finder

How do I make this window larger by default so whenever I use 'open a file' in any program, it's not super small?

I am referring to the window size, not the text size.

I have the Finder (outside of 'open a file') larger by default, but I am unsure how to make this one larger.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about making the window bigger by default or the size of the text displayed in a window?

Comment: ah yes sorry, the window, not the text display. I have updated the original question now to clarifiy

Comment: Can't you just drag the corner like normal?

Comment: @unbeatable101 The OP wants the computer to do that for him not have to do it manually each time

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking a window remembers the last size it was set to before closing it. That can and will be overridden on an individual folder basis. EG a folder will *usually* remember the size and position of the finder window that was opened to view it.

Unfortunately the days of a truly spatial Finder went away with macOS X. So the Mac does not always remember the window size, icon arrangement and such. A feature I *really* miss from the Classic MacOS days.

But, again, macOS should remember the size that the last Finder window that was opened.

Comment: OP is showing a file picker dialog - although the same rule should apply as you stated. Each app should remember the size you dragged the file picker to.

Comment: A common complaint with Big Sur seems to be that it resets the size of dialogs to some default each time they are opened.  Don't have direct experience, have no reason to bother installing Big Sur before it reaches .6, at least.  Is that a Big Sur dialog?

Comment: yeah so finder works fine, I have that set as a default, but it is the open file 'finder' that I need.  each time I go to open a file in any program it is small and I have to resize it, even when I open a file, resize, open another file it is super small again.  And yes, this is on Bit Sur